# android input fields affect each other

Tags: android, android-edittext, oncheckedchanged

In Android I have multiple form widgets in the same View and I'd like to have them affect each other.  Right now I have an EditText field that you can type an integer into and I'd like to have the value show up in a series of ToggleButtons (i.e. the binary value of the EditText field shows up as selected buttons).  I'd like for both fields to affect each other, so clicking a button changes the text and changing the text changes the button.

Right now I'm using the `afterTextChanged()` method to catch the updated text and change the buttons.  I'm using the `onCheckedChanged()` method to catch the updated button clicks and change the text.

It works going in either direction, but when they're both in there, they call each other, which can lead to undesirable behavior.  Is there a way to change the state of a field without calling its 'change handler' or is there another handler that will work better to avoid the recursive calls?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setText()` method of the EditText to set the value of the when it is changed by a user changing the toggle button values.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this was to use a state variable to add a 'semaphore.'  In the event handlers I'd check to see if the handler was called from another handler and not re-update the original field if so.